# onOptionsItemSelected not getting called when using custom action view

Tags: android

I set an custom view for one of my actionbar MenuBar like this

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.loop_thread, menu);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.image_container, null));
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_filter).setActionView(iv);
        ...
```

but when I tap that menu item in my app, `onOptionsItemSelected()` does not get called. (I have verified this via setting a breakpoint at the beginning of the method). If I tap the other buttons, in Action bar, onOptionsItemSelected() does get called.

here is the xml code fo rmy custom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ibtnFilterMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_action_down_arrow"
    style = "@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"/>
```

I've also tried setting the Action view on the menu xml file :

```
    <item android:id="@+id/action_filter"
    android:title="@string/filter_options"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/image_container"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Note: I know I can make the image clickable, and manually set an onClickListener for it, but for the sake of learning, I want to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: And how looks your `onOptionsItemSelected()` method?

Comment: it doesn't matter, I have a breakpoint set at the beginning of the method, and it doesn't get called at all.

Comment: Did you try the `setActionView` method, that accepts resource ID instead of the view, you inflate manually?

Comment: Yes :/.... I think maybe the setActionView draws the custom View on top of the MenuItem, and therefore the touch events get routed to the View instead of the ActionBar. Does that sound right?

Comment: @Siavash why do you use `setActionView`, you already set it in your layout  `android:actionLayout="@layout/image_container"`

Comment: @mmlooloo I don't do both, I've tried both ways of setting the actionView, but not at the same time.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It seems that the underlying code that inflates and draws the action items, doesn't connect the contents of the custom layout set by `setActionView()` or by the `android:actionLayout="@layout/image_container"`.

Probably because the layout can be anything, and just a button or image. So I must manually set the `onClickListener` for the icon.  For the purpose of organization, I just call `onOptionsItemSelected()` from the `OnClick` method of my icon, but I could just define the action inside the `onClick` method.

first, declare filterMenuItem in your `Activity`.

```
MenuItem filterMenuItem;

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.loop_thread, menu);
    filterMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_filter);

    filterMenuItem.getActionView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity.this.onOptionsItemSelected(filterMenuItem);
    }
});
```

Comment: In onClick method you should call onMenuItemSelected(0, filterMenuItem);  instead if you want to propagate calls to onOptionsItemSelected through implementations in fragments of your activity.

Comment: Using actionlayout makes my item not respond with ripple on click, is this default behaviour?

Comment: Yes, it depends what you are putting in the custom layout. Just use `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` on your image/imageButton if you want the ripple effect

Comment: return true needed?

Answer (score -2):

you have to call menu.add() method and implemenet onPreareOptionsmenu instead of oncreateoptionsmenu method. This is my code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {                

        menu.clear();       
        if(mAlbum.getStatus() == Album.STATUS_VIDEO_AVAILABLE)
        {
            menu.add(0, 0 , 0, getString(R.string.edit_album))
            .setIcon(R.drawable.edit_album_icon);
            menu.add(0, 1 , 0, getString(R.string.delete_album))
            .setIcon(R.drawable.delete_album_icon);
            menu.add(0, 2 , 0, getString(R.string.download_video))
            .setIcon(R.drawable.download_vdo_icon);
            menu.add(0, 3 , 0, getString(R.string.upload_to_ambivo))
            .setIcon(R.drawable.share_ambivo_icon);
            menu.add(0, 4 , 0, getString(R.string.upload_to_facebook))
            .setIcon(R.drawable.share_fb_icon);
            menu.add(0, 5 , 0, getString(R.string.upload_to_youtube))
            .setIcon(R.drawable.share_yt_icon);

        }
        else{
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.albummenu, menu);
            if(mAlbum.getAlbumType() == Album.COMPOSITE_VIDEOS)
                menu.findItem(R.id.convert_album).setVisible(false);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? call menu.add() where?