# What is the right way and right time in activity life cycle to get view of a menu item in android?

Tags: android

> What I've tried so far, but no success:

- In `menuItem`'s `xml` set `android:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageView"` and in `activity`'s `onCreateOptionsMenu` use `getActionView` on `menuItem`
- Call `findViewById(menuItemId)` in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` or `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` or `onResume()`. (View is always `null`)

> What works?

- In `onCreateOptionsMenu()` I used `new Handler().post(new Runnable())` to call `findViewById(menuItemId)`. This works!

> The issue?

I am not satisfied with the code structure. It is not readable. I believe there must be a better way to do this!

> I need answers to these questions:

1. What is the **right way** to get **view** of **menuItem**?
2. What is the **right time in activity life cycle** to get view of menuItem?

Answer (score 1):

The first approach was correct. You get the ActionView of your menu item in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. For this to work you need to define the Layout of your MenuItem like `app:actionLayout="@layout/myLayout"`.

An example can be found on https://stackoverflow.com/a/26259527/1505074

Comment: I am not using a custom layout. What can I set as `actionLayout` if I want to use the default layout provided by android iteself?

Comment: I do not know if there is a way to set the actionLayout as default, but you can just put your icon in an ImageView which is the layout for the custom layout. I hope this helps...

Comment: Good thought! Let me quickly test the same. Thanks!

Comment: Christian, I appreciate your efforts. Since I have already figured out how to access `menuItemView` in `onCreateOptionsMenu`, implementing this answer isn't a step up from current implementation. My requirement was to better the implementation by being able to move code from `onCreateOptionsMenu` to `onResume` or something to make it readable. Your answer is nonetheless very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This answer may be helpful for the question " To show an overlay on an activity's menu item view in my app." before you edited the question.

How I achieved showing ShowcaseView on Menu Item was by using Toolbar. So Inside onCreate() what you can do is -

```
Target target = new ViewTarget(getToolBar().getChildAt(0));

new ShowcaseView.Builder(this)
                .setTarget(target)
                .build();
```

`new getChildAt(0)` will give you the home button. Similarly for other icons you can try changing parameter inside `getChildAt()` method.

Comment: Update: `getChildAt(1)` is for toolbar home/back icon, `getChildAt(0)` is for toolbar title, `getChildAt(-1)` and `getChildAt(2)` result in null.

Comment: To get menu item try `Target target = new ViewTarget(R.id.id_of_menu_item);`

Comment: Thanks, just a correction: `Target target = new ViewTarget(R.id.menuItemId, activity);` Let me quickly try this

Comment: This too returns `null` view. Probably because `onCreateOptionsMenu` hasn't finished inflating `menu` yet.