# How to get and populate a menu item created through custom layout?

Tags: android, layout, menu

I've been trying to load an image into a menu item which has been created through a custom layout and have been checking on the official documentation and on posts such as these [Custom view for Menu Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26259162/custom-view-for-menu-item) but..

That's my onCreateOptionsMenu ond OnPrepareOptionsMenu

```
  @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        final MenuItem alertMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_my_personal);
        FrameLayout rootView = (FrameLayout) alertMenuItem.getActionView();

        redCircle = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_alert_red_circle);
        countTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_alert_count_textview);
        ImageView hc_image_menu_inflated = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.hc_image_menu);

        rootView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onOptionsItemSelected(alertMenuItem);
            }
        });


        if (menu.findItem(R.id.hc_image_menu) != null) {
            loadMenuIcon(menu.findItem(R.id.hc_image_menu), my_image_url);
        }

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu_main, menu);

        return true;
    }
```

As you can see I have added these lines to avoid the app crashing, as menu.finditem(R.id.hc_image_menu) is returning as null and that's where the problem is, as I want to populate the ImageView that has the id *hc_image_menu* but am not being successful despite so many attempts

```
 if (menu.findItem(R.id.hc_image_menu) != null) {
        loadMenuIcon(menu.findItem(R.id.hc_image_menu), my_image_url);
    }
```

My code for my *toolbar_main_menu* layout is this:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_my_personal"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/toolbar_menu_hc"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="My Personal Trainer"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
```

And for my custom layout (*toolbar_hc_menu*) is this one:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="48dp"
android:layout_height="32dp"
android:layout_gravity="center">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/hc_image_menu"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/gavin"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/view_alert_red_circle"
    android:layout_width="14dp"
    android:layout_height="14dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top|end"
    android:background="@drawable/date_circle"
    android:visibility="gone"
    tools:visibility="visible">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view_alert_count_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        tools:text="3"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks very much for any help on that. Really much appreciated!! :)

Comment: hc_image_menu is not a menu item

Comment: Hi @nomag Thanks very much for your reply. Yes, I know that, but just don't know how to get the proper menu item that is associated with the hc_image_menu image view? Thanks again!

Comment: You already have menuItem : alertMenuItem . Isn't it ?

Comment: Thanks @nomag I didn't realise it was easier than I thought. I was just so focused on working on the menu item but actually only had to load the image into the image view after getting the alertMenuItem. Doing everything as normal then.. Thanks very much for your help on that! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue fixed. :)
At the end I just had to load the image into the ImageView after having got the alertMenuItem.

```
if (my_image_url!= null) {
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(my_image_url).into(hc_image_menu_inflated);
    }
```