# How to display text below icon in option menu?

Tags: android, optionmenu

Does anyone have an idea about how to customize the options menu item?. so I need to change display text below icon of the option menu item in a toolbar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom view for Menu Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26259162/custom-view-for-menu-item)

Comment: @ADM I want to display text below icon?.

Comment: Yeah you can do that by using a custom view .

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Custom toolbar :-

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_imageView"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/card_h"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/card_h"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/small_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/med_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/small_margin"
            android:src="@mipmap/back" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/right_iv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/iv_dob"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/first_textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colortext"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text_size" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: this text display near icon .

Comment: Use custom toolbar. Modified above code @DaminiMehra

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom action Layout and put into menu Item:

Here is XML for menu.

```
<menu 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:Eventapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
android:id="@+id/action_create"
android:actionLayout="@layout/action_view_details_layout"
android:orderInCategory="50"
android:showAsAction = "always"/>

</menu>
```

The Layout is

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="@string/create"/>

<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/icon"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

this will show the icon and the text in vertical fashion.

Comment: this is a good idea but I have lots of items in an options menu.so I need to make lots of layout for all the menu items.

Comment: no you can use single layout for menu item and use it at all places .

Comment: then how can I change image icon dynamically?

Comment: If yo want to display more than 4 items you should consider **bottomsheet** or **Popupdialog** to display those options to user. this will look good and will give  you more control for design and event handling.