# OnOptionsItemSelected not being called for Action Bar Menu Item with custom actionLayout

Tags: android, xamarin, android-actionbar

I'm trying to implement a notification icon in my actionbar to show the count of notifications. Something like

[image]

I've added a custom layout file for it **NotificationIcon.xml**:

```
  <!-- Menu Item Image -->
  <ImageButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="2dp"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:src="@drawable/notification" />

  <!-- Badge Count -->
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/actionbar_notifcation_textview"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      android:minWidth="20dp"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:background="@drawable/circle_green"
      android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:text="0"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And used it in my menu as **main_activity_actions.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
        android:id="@+id/action_add"
        android:title="@string/AddTag"
        android:icon="@+drawable/ic_action_new"
        android:showAsAction="always" />
  <item
        android:id="@+id/notification_icon"
        android:title="@string/PendingJobs"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/notificationIcon"
        android:icon="@+drawable/notification"
        android:showAsAction="always" />
  <item
        android:id="@+id/gps_status_icon"
        android:title="@string/GPS"
        android:icon="@+drawable/gps_grey"
        android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

The UI looks fine but the OnOptionsItemSelected is not being called for the notification icon. It works fine for the other two.
I did google this and ound this link: [onOptionsItemSelected not getting called when using custom action view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26170423/onoptionsitemselected-not-getting-called-when-using-custom-action-view)

I tried to implement it in my main activity:

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {
            actionBarMenu = menu;
            MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.main_activity_actions, menu);

            var notificationMenuItem = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.notification_icon);
            notificationMenuItem.ActionView.Click += (sender, args) => {
                this.OnOptionsItemSelected(notificationMenuItem);
            };

            return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
```

but it does not works for me. It never fires the click event.
Please help.

Comment: you have to set your own click listeners for custom layout of actionbar

Comment: @GopalSinghSirvi I have, please see the last piece of code. But the click is not getting fired.

Comment: I have written the code to solve your problem....please use it and let me know if it helps you to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();

                inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);

        final View notification_icon= menu.findItem(R.id.notification_icon).getActionView();


        notification_icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
// write ur code here
}

        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

use this code......hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I was hoping for a c# version of the same as I'm working in Xamarin. Even so, this is the same as the code I used, I converted it myself from the java snippet from the answer in the link link I included in my question. Please tell what I could have done differently.

Answer (score 0):

i struggle with the same Problem and found following Solution:

First of all: i really don't know why but if you delete the

```
android:clickable="true"
```

then ... and ONLY then you get the click event!!!

Second: you have to set the Listener...

```
...    
item.getActionView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Do Your Stuff.....
        }
});
```

May someone can Explain why this is with the "android:clickable" Thing... i tough the standard value IS true??

Answer (score 0):

You had made ImageButton clickable, and then written the clickListener for the Layout of menuItem. You can observe that if you click outside the ImageButton but inside the MenuItem layout, your listener will work. The reason is simple clickListener for ImageButton has nothing to do, on setting Clickable = true defines whether this button reacts to click events. Just simply set Clickable = false, your button will not react to its click event, eventually your whole layout will react to your defined clickListener and then your problem will be solved.