# onOptionsItemSelected in Menu is not clickable for item using actionLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, optionmenu

I have an android app with options menu, and the first item is defined with "actionLayout":

menu.xml snippet:

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/Cart"
    android:title="Cart"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/custom_action_item_layout"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_white_24dp"
    android:title="@string/settings"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

custom_action_item_layout snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/cart"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:focusable="true"
android:clickable="true">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_white_24dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cart_badge"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right|end|top"
    android:layout_marginEnd="-5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/badge_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"

    android:textSize="12sp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

then I set the menu up:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu_: Menu): Boolean {
    menu = menu_
    val inflater = menuInflater
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.uppermenu, menu)

    var cart = menu!!.findItem(R.id.Cart);
    var actionView = getActionView(cart);

    textCartItemCount = actionView.findViewById(R.id.cart_badge) as TextView

    return true

}
```

however, the

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean { }
```

is never called when I click on the menu item.

I looked up the solution for the sherlockactionbar from 2012 for java, but the solution does not apply well:
[onOptionsItemSelected not called when using actionLayout (SherlockActionBar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627892/onoptionsitemselected-not-called-when-using-actionlayout-sherlockactionbar)

It seems related to the action Layout of the item, Without this, it is working well.
how to make the onOptionsItemSelected working?

Comment: You have to add onClickListener for your menu item? Just let me know what do you want to perform when the user clicks the menu item

Comment: I call a method and update the textview that is inside the custom_action_item_layout it is similiar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617771/onoptionsitemselected-not-being-called-for-action-bar-menu-item-with-custom-acti?rq=1

Comment: I have updated the answer for you and just check and let me know if it works for you

Comment: I still would like to know why the method is not called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu_: Menu): Boolean {
    menu = menu_
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.uppermenu, menu)
    var cartMenuItem = menu!!.findItem(R.id.Cart)
    cartMenuItem.actionView?.cart.setOnClickListener {
          cartMenuItem.actionView?.cart_badge.text = "content update in the textview"
    }
    return true
}
```

The above snippet should perform onClick event for you

Comment: Yes, I got it working with:         actionView.setOnClickListener { view ->
            // Do some work here
        }

Comment: Please accept the answer so that it will serve as a reference for others

Comment: any glue why the method is not called?

Comment: @RaghulVaikundam, how did you get the .cart `cartMenuItem.actionView?.cart`?

Answer (score 0):

Using the new `MenuProvider` interface:

```
requireActivity().addMenuProvider(
    object : MenuProvider {
        override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.uppermenu, menu)
            val cartMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.Cart)

            cartMenuItem.actionView?.cart.setOnClickListener {
                cartMenuItem.actionView?.cart_badge.text = "content update in the textview"
            }
        }

        override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
            // click action handled in onCreateMenu.
            return false
        }
    }, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.STARTED
)
```

Note that the action view needs to set `android:clickable="true"` and `android:focusable="true"`